# Firebase - sort posts by number of keys and show in TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have made app that save users message and its username to Firebase with childByAutoID key. Inside there are childs that saves Username, message, likes and PostID (as you can see on image below).

[image]

After a lot of research and a lot of trying writing code by myself, I figure out that likes need to be saved as autoID keys inside separate child and then you have to count that keys to get number of likes (you'll see that child also on image under and that child is named "Liked")

[image]

Everything is displayed in tableView cell.
But all of them are displayed randomly which is OK (I would prefer to be ordered by date added), but what would really like is that loaded data in next next VC to be displayed as:

TOP 10 of the week
TOP 10 of the month
ALL BEST etc...

There'll be separate button for menu and when you press it, you'll be presented with next VC that contain Table View with same data, but this time sorted by most liked post.

This is code that writes keys to LIKED child path (when like is pressed on already loaded data from Firebase database):

```
    @IBAction func likePressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    self.likeButton.isEnabled = false
    let key = ref.child("Frusters").childByAutoId().key

    ref.child("Frusters").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                let updateLikes = ["Liked/\(key)" : key] as [String : Any]
                    ref.child("Frusters").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(updateLikes, withCompletionBlock: { (error, reff) in

                        if error == nil {
                            ref.child("Frusters").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
                        if let properties = snap.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                        if let likes = properties["Liked"] as? [String : AnyObject] {

                        let count = likes.count
                        self.likeLabel.text = "\(count) Likes"

                        let update = ["likes" : count]
                        ref.child("Frusters").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(update)

                        self.likeButton.isHidden = true
                        self.unlikeButton.isHidden = false
                        self.likeButton.isEnabled = true
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })

    ref.removeAllObservers()
}
```

and this is the code that loads data and put it in my table view:

```
    func loadData() {
    self.fetchPosts.removeAll()
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("Frusters").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            for (_,postElement) in postDict {
                print(postElement);
                let post = Post()
                post.username = postElement["Username"] as? String
                post.message = postElement["Message"] as? String
                post.likes = postElement["likes"] as? Int
                post.postID = postElement["postID"] as? String
                self.fetchPosts.append(post)
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    ref.removeAllObservers()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.fetchPosts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")  as! PostTableViewCell

    cell.messageLabel.text = self.fetchPosts[indexPath.row].message
    cell.usernameLabel.text = self.fetchPosts[indexPath.row].username

    cell.likeLabel.text = "\(self.fetchPosts[indexPath.row].likes!) Likes"
    cell.postID = self.fetchPosts[indexPath.row].postID

    cell.bckgView.layer.cornerRadius = 0

    cell.bckgView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
    cell.bckgView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.bckgView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.bckgView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    cell.bckgView.layer.shadowRadius = 4

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Well, problem is that I do not know how to insert inside my new UITableView top 10 post with most likes, to sort them from most liked post to next 9 of them with most likes.

Also, is it possible to sort them most liked this month or this week?
Does this keys that Firebase database makes (by autoID) contain date of created post or do I have to insert new child with date inside and then in code combine "date" child and "liked" child to be presented as top 10 liked post between 1st and last of this month?

Thanks in advance. ;)

Comment: for Top 10 of the Month and Top 10 of the week you need to add CreationDate for that Post and sort by likes(number of likes) .

Comment: I am reading Firebase documentation and there is some explanation, but not enough for me. :/ Was searching for answers here, find something with server timestamp, but I am still learning and I am not that kind of expert to code it by myself. I'll try to find something else and try to use code what I have found till now. Thank you for answering my question @NishantBhindi

Comment: Maybe inside me loadData() I should insert: let postOrderMostLikes = ref.child("Frusters").child(self.postID).queryOrdered(byChild: "likes") ?

Maybe this will sort all of my post by number of likes?

Comment: This is so frustrated. I have search every day for answer, tried so many codes and now officially I give up. There is no way I can do this. I am going to try something else.

Answer (score 0):

1-You don't have to store each like separately, if all you care about is the number. You can just update the number.

```
    @IBAction func likePressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    self.likeButton.isEnabled = false
    let key = ref.child("Frusters").childByAutoId().key

    ref.child("Frusters").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    let counted = snapshot.value as? Int
    self.ref.child("Flusters".child(self.postID).child("likes").setValue(counted! + 1)
})
```

2- Yes, you can sort by likes. you'd need to use the .queryOrdered function. Update the code as follows

```
func loadData() {
    self.fetchPosts.removeAll()
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("Frusters").queryOrdered(byChild: "likes").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            for (_,postElement) in postDict {
                print(postElement);
                let post = Post()
                post.username = postElement["Username"] as? String
                post.message = postElement["Message"] as? String
                post.likes = postElement["likes"] as? Int
                post.postID = postElement["postID"] as? String
                self.fetchPosts.append(post)
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
```

3- To order by top week, month, you'd have to keep track of a timestamp.